# Obtener últimos doce datos y promediarlos de forma dinámica en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo una tabla que maneja cifras MENSUALES de los ultimos 3 años,
en este caso 2016, 2017 y 2018.

Aca muestro una imagen simplificada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ej1: "q_m01_p_a"  esa es enero por el "01" del año 2016 por la letra "a"

ej2: "q_m02_p_b"  esa es febrero por el "02" del año 2017 por la letra "b"

ej3: "q_m03_p_c"  esa es marzo por el "03" del año 2018 por la letra "c"

Necesito obtener un promedio de los datos que se encuentran en los ultimos 12 meses,
actualmente estamos en el mes 6 del 2018
por ende el campo promedio debe calcularme el promedio de mayo 2017 a mayo 2018.

Necesito me puedan orientar con alguna funcion.

Se que con CURDATE() puedo obtener la fecha actual del sistema.

Necesito me puedan ayudar con esta query o varias query que pueda hacer en un SP que me ayude a calcular este PROMEDIO.

La idea es que sea dinámico.

Comment: Hola, ¿has intentando crear el stored procedure? Cuando dices que necesitas una función asumo que solo te refieres a la forma de calcular los 6 meses anteriores con respecto al día actual.

Comment: hasta el momento no he creado el SP, debido a que desconozco si existe alguna función que pueda simplificar mi trabajo.
lo que pienso es realizar un select de cada mes y año y pasarlo a una variable, lo cual serian 36 variables, ya que tengo los últimos 3 años registrados. luego de eso tratar de trabajar con las variables tomando la fecha actual del sistema, y asemejarla con el numero de la tupla que significa el mes "q_m01_p_a" ej: esa es enero por el "01" del año 2016 por la letra "a"

Comment: Me parece que se complica un poco porque no veo que tengas alguna columna con la fecha, lo ideal hubiera sido que tengas los campos: `año`, `mes`, `monto`, o algo parecido.

Comment: Teniendo un campo fecha, podrás lograrlo con dos combinaciones muy simples: `ORDER BY campo_fecha DESC LIMIT 12`... así te traerá los últimos 12 registros. ¿Ese `campo_fecha`
 existe en tu tabla? Si no existe... ¿por qué no existe? En cuanto al formato de la pregunta, evita poner todo en mayúsculas, es de mal gusto en el medio informático. Gracias.

Comment: A. Cedano es una base de datos totalmente desnormalizada,necesito sabr el mes actual, que eso lo puedo saber con CURDATE() a partir de ese dato pararme en la tupla anterior "q_m05_p_c" que seria mayo hasta los 12 meses anteriores osea de  "q_m05_p_b" a "q_m05_p_c", y esos datos promediarlos y mostrarlos en PROMEDIO. digamos que no existe un formato de fecha, solo existe los 01 al 12 dentro de cada campo como info :(

Comment: Pues tienes dos soluciones: 1. Normalizar la base de datos agregando un campo fecha... es algo que tendrás que hacer ahora o dentro de unos meses/años, sobre todo si la BD tiene tendencia a crecer. Entiendo que a veces hay limitaciones cómo que no tengas privilegios para crear nuevas columnas, etc, etc, etc  Aún así el camino correcto es normalizar. Si no se puede por ahora, entonces tendrás que invertir tiempo en crear tu propio algoritmo para determinar lo que quieres en base a la fecha actual como bien dices.

Comment: realice el SP finalmente, me tuve que tomar de un único dato que tenia un formato similar a la fecha 'FECHAE_EST' Gracias por sus sugerencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
                PROCEDURE PLANILLA_OO1_25_PROMEDIO_VENTAS()
                BEGIN


                declare fecha_actual date;
                declare fecha_12 date;
                declare fecha_11 date;
                declare fecha_10 date;
                declare fecha_09 date;
                declare fecha_08 date;
                declare fecha_07 date;
                declare fecha_06 date;
                declare fecha_05 date;
                declare fecha_04 date;
                declare fecha_03 date;
                declare fecha_02 date;
                declare fecha_01 date;

                declare mes_12  varchar(2);
                declare mes_11  varchar(2);
                declare mes_10  varchar(2);
                declare mes_09  varchar(2);
                declare mes_08  varchar(2);
                declare mes_07  varchar(2);
                declare mes_06  varchar(2);
                declare mes_05  varchar(2);
                declare mes_04  varchar(2);
                declare mes_03  varchar(2);
                declare mes_02  varchar(2);
                declare mes_01  varchar(2);

                declare anno_12 varchar(4);
                declare anno_11 varchar(4);
                declare anno_10 varchar(4);
                declare anno_09 varchar(4);
                declare anno_08 varchar(4);
                declare anno_07 varchar(4);
                declare anno_06 varchar(4);
                declare anno_05 varchar(4);
                declare anno_04 varchar(4);
                declare anno_03 varchar(4);
                declare anno_02 varchar(4);
                declare anno_01 varchar(4);


                declare VALOR_01 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_02 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_03 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_04 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_05 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_06 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_07 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_08 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_09 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_10 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_11 INT (11);
                declare VALOR_12 INT (11);

                declare ANO_MES_12 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_11 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_10 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_09 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_08 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_07 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_06 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_05 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_04 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_03 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_02 int(11);
                declare ANO_MES_01 int(11);

                declare VALOR_SUMADO_PROMEDIO INT (11);

                declare codigo_new varchar(20);




                DECLARE no_hay_mas_registros INT DEFAULT 0; 


                DECLARE elCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT CODIGO  FROM PLANILLA_001 ;

                SET fecha_actual = (SELECT CURDATE());
                SET fecha_12 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
                SET fecha_11 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);
                SET fecha_10 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
                SET fecha_09 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 4 MONTH);
                SET fecha_08 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 5 MONTH);
                SET fecha_07 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
                SET fecha_06 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 7 MONTH);
                SET fecha_05 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 8 MONTH);
                SET fecha_04 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 9 MONTH);
                SET fecha_03 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 10 MONTH);
                SET fecha_02 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 11 MONTH);
                SET fecha_01 = (SELECT fecha_actual - INTERVAL 12 MONTH);

                SET mes_12  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_12,'%m'));
                SET mes_11  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_11,'%m'));
                SET mes_10  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_10,'%m'));
                SET mes_09  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_09,'%m'));
                SET mes_08  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_08,'%m'));
                SET mes_07  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_07,'%m'));
                SET mes_06  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_06,'%m'));
                SET mes_05  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_05,'%m'));
                SET mes_04  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_04,'%m'));
                SET mes_03  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_03,'%m'));
                SET mes_02  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_02,'%m'));
                SET mes_01  = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_01,'%m'));

                SET anno_12 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_12,'%Y'));
                SET anno_11 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_11,'%Y'));
                SET anno_10 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_10,'%Y'));
                SET anno_09 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_09,'%Y'));
                SET anno_08 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_08,'%Y'));
                SET anno_07 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_07,'%Y'));
                SET anno_06 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_06,'%Y'));
                SET anno_05 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_05,'%Y'));
                SET anno_04 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_04,'%Y'));
                SET anno_03 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_03,'%Y'));
                SET anno_02 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_02,'%Y'));
                SET anno_01 = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_01,'%Y'));


                SET ANO_MES_12 = CONCAT (anno_12,mes_12);
                SET ANO_MES_11 = CONCAT (anno_11,mes_11);
                SET ANO_MES_10 = CONCAT (anno_10,mes_10);
                SET ANO_MES_09 = CONCAT (anno_09,mes_09);
                SET ANO_MES_08 = CONCAT (anno_08,mes_08);
                SET ANO_MES_07 = CONCAT (anno_07,mes_07);
                SET ANO_MES_06 = CONCAT (anno_06,mes_06);
                SET ANO_MES_05 = CONCAT (anno_05,mes_05);
                SET ANO_MES_04 = CONCAT (anno_04,mes_04);
                SET ANO_MES_03 = CONCAT (anno_03,mes_03);
                SET ANO_MES_02 = CONCAT (anno_02,mes_02);
                SET ANO_MES_01 = CONCAT (anno_01,mes_01);




                open elCursor;
                -- se van tomando los datos hasta que el cursor llegue al final
                bucle: loop

                fetch elCursor into codigo_new;
                if (no_hay_mas_registros = 1) then
                leave bucle;
                end if;


                SET  VALOR_12 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_12
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_12
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_12
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_12
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_12
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_12
                ) T);


                SET  VALOR_11 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_11
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_11
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_11
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_11
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_11
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_11
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_10 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_10
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_10
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_10
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_10
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_10
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_10
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_09 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_09
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_09
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_09
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_09
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_09
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_09
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_08 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_08
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_08
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_08
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_08
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_08
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_08
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_07 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_07
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_07
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_07
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_07
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_07
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_07
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_06 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_06
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_06
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_06
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_06
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_06
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_06
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_05 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_05
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_05
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_05
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_05
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_05
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_05
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_04 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_04
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_04
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_04
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_04
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_04
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_04
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_03 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_03
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_03
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_03
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_03
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_03
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_03
                ) T);

                SET  VALOR_02 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_02
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_02
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_02
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_02
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_02
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_02
                ) T);


                SET  VALOR_01 = (SELECT SUM(T.VENTAS_EST)
                FROM (SELECT VENTAS_EST   FROM tb1 WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_01
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb2   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_01
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST  FROM tb3   WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_01
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb4  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_01
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb5  WHERE CODIGO_EST=codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_01
                UNION
                SELECT VENTAS_EST FROM tb6 WHERE CODIGO_EST = codigo_new AND FECHAE_EST= ANO_MES_01
                ) T);


                SET  VALOR_SUMADO_PROMEDIO = (select IFNULL(VALOR_01,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_02,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_03,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_04,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_05,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_06,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_07,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_08,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_09,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_10,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_11,0)+IFNULL(VALOR_12,0))/12 ;






                IF (SELECT count(CODIGO) as conteo from PLANILLA_001 WHERE  CODIGO  = codigo_new ) = 1 THEN 



                UPDATE PLANILLA_001 SET PROMEDIO = VALOR_SUMADO_PROMEDIO  WHERE  CODIGO  = codigo_new ;


                END IF;





                end loop bucle;
                close elCursor;







                END
```